# A question regarding a double series.

Tags: analysis

> Let $\{a_{mn}\}$ be a double series, where $a_{mn}>0$ for all $m,n\in\Bbb{N}$. If $\sum\limits_{i=1}^\infty{a_{ik}}$ is finite for all $k\in\Bbb{N}$ and $\sum\limits_{j=1}^\infty{a_{hj}}$ is finite for all $j\in\Bbb{N}$, then $\sum\limits_{i=1}^\infty \sum\limits_{j=1}^\infty{a_{ij}}=\sum\limits_{j=1}^\infty\sum\limits_{i=1}^\infty{a_{ij}}$.

1. Is the above statement true?
2. If it is, how does one go about proving it?

Comment: see http://www.jstor.org/stable/1967602?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents

Comment: @DavidMitra- I forgot to mention that all $a_{mn}$ need to be positive.

Comment: You can also find this in the classic and very readable old textbook Infinite Sequences And Series by Bromwich.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, for nonnegative sequence $\{a_{mn}\}$, we always have $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{m=1}^\infty a_{mn}=\sum_{m=1}^\infty\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_{mn}.$$

This can be proved by monotone convergence theorem. Note that both sides could be $+\infty$.

For general sequence $\{a_{mn}\}$, if $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{m=1}^\infty|a_{mn}|<\infty$, then
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{m=1}^\infty a_{mn}=\sum_{m=1}^\infty\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_{mn}.$$

This can be proved by Fubini's Theorem or Lebesgue Dominated Convergence Theorem.

Answer (score 0):

If a double series is absolutely convergent, it is also convergent; moreover, any series obtained by rearrangement of its terms also converges,
https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Double_series